# How to describe free objects $GA, GA'$ for non algebraic categories.

Tags: category-theory, definition, functors

The following question is taken from *Arrows, Structures and Functors the categorical imperative* by Arbib and Manes and "Theory of Mathematical Structures" by Jiří Adamek

$\color{Green}{Background:}$

We have these two definitions:

$\textbf{(1) Definition for Functors:}$  A functor $H$ from a category $\textbf{K}$ to a  category $\textbf{L}$ is a function which maps $\text{Obj}\textbf{(K)}\to \text{Obj}\textbf{(L)}:A\mapsto HA,$ and which for each pair $A,B$ of objects $\textbf{K}$ maps $\textbf{K}(A,B)\to \textbf{L}(HA, HB):f\mapsto Hf,$ while satisfying the two conditions:

$H(\text{id}_A) = \text{id}_{\text{HA}}$ $\quad$ $\text{ for every }$ $A \in \text{Obj}(\textbf{K})$

$H(g\cdot f)=Hg\cdot Hf \quad\text{ whenever }g\cdot f\text{ is defined in }\textbf{K}.$

We say that $H$ is an $\textbf{isomorphism}$ if $A\mapsto HA$ and each $\textbf{K}(A,B)\to \textbf{L}(HA, HB)$ are bijections.

$\textbf{(2)Definition for "free over an object with respect to a functor":}$  Let $G:\textbf{A}\to \textbf{B}$ be any functor, and  $B$ an object of $\textbf{B}.$  We say the pair $(A,\eta),$ where $A$ is an object of $\textbf{A}$ and $\eta:B\to GA$ is a morphism of $\textbf{B},$ is $\textbf{free over}$ $B$ $\textbf{with respect to}$ $G$ just in case $\eta;B\to GA$ has the couniversal property that given any morphism $f:B\to GA'$ with $A'$ any object of $\textbf{A,}$ there exists a unique $\textbf{A-}$morphism $\psi:A\to A';$ such that

Diagram 1

[image: Diagram 1]

We refer to $\eta$ as the $\textbf{inclusion of generators;}$ and call the unique $\psi$ satisfying the above diagram the $\textbf{A-morphic extension of } f$ (with respect to $G$).

We have the following three categories:

[From Arbib and Manes]

$\textbf{(3)}$ Category $\textbf{Top},$

For topological spaces, we have category $\textbf{Top},$ with topologies $\tau_X,$ $\tau_Y$ as objects and continuous maps $f:X\to Y$ as morphisms, that maps open set to open sets, $O_{\tau_Y}\in  \tau_Y, O_{\tau_Y}\subset Y$ implies $f^{-1}(O_{\tau_Y})\in \tau_X, f^{-1}(O_{\tau_Y})\subset X.$

$\textbf{(4)}$ Subcategory metric space $\textbf{K}$ with lipschitz map, and $\lambda>1$:

The subcategory of Metric Space $\textbf{K}$ (contractive map) with $(X,d)$ and $(Y,e)$ defined as categories, elements of $X$ as objects, and morphisms  $x\to x'$ defined as $\lambda\geq d(x,x')$

[From Adamek]

$\textbf{(5)}$ Category metric space $\textbf{Met}$ with lipschitz map $\lambda=1$:

Category of $\textbf{Met}:$  The construct $\textbf{Met}$ has as objects all $\textit{metric spaces,}$ i.e., pairs $(X,\alpha)$ where $X$ is a set and $\alpha$ is its metric.  The morphisms from a space $(X,\alpha)$ to a space $(Y,\beta),$ called $\textit{contractions,}$ are maps

$f:X\to Y$

such that

$\beta(f(x_1),f(x_2))\leq \alpha(x_1,x_2)\quad \forall x_1,x_2\in X.$

$\color{Red}{Questions:}$

I am having difficulty figuring out what the codomain $GA$ of the morphism $\eta \in \textbf{B}$ is suppose to be in definition $\textbf{(2)},$ for the three non algebraic categories listed in $\textbf{(3)},\textbf{(4)},$ and $\textbf{(5)}.$ For all three cases, we can let $\textbf{B}=\textbf{Set},$ the category of set, and $B$ to be an object in $\textbf{B}.$  Both $A, A'$ are objects in $\textbf{A}.$ In the context of the three categories $\textbf{(3), (4),(5)},$ category $\textbf{A},$ depending on which of those three is to be respectively $\textbf{Top, K, Met.}$ with objects $A,A'$ in $\textbf{A}.$ In the context of those three categories the objects $A,A'$ are also respectively: $\tau_X, \tau_Y, x_1,x_2, (X,\alpha), (Y,\beta).$ We have the morphism $\psi\in \textbf{A},$ and the functor $G\psi:GA\to GA'.$  I don't know how to describe $GA, GA',$ for each of the three categories, even though I know how to write the functor for each of them.  Hence I don't know what $\eta(b), b\in B$ suppose to equal to other than that $\eta(b)\in GA,$ and for the same reason, $f(b)\in GA'.$ Thank you in advance.

Comment: The definition of freeness takes an arbitrary functor $G$ as input, so in some sense it's up to you. However traditionally in this context $G$ is the forgetful / underlying set functor, so $GA$ is just the underlying set of $A$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan sorry, I don't understand.  What does it mean it is up to me?   I thought there should be some systemic way of finding out what $GA$ is suppose to be?  Also $A$ is an object in the category $\textbf{A}.$  For example in the case of $\textbf{Top},$ it would be $\tau_X,$ a topology defined on set $X$.  How is that consider an underlying set?  Also, doesn't that make the direct image $\eta(B),$ to be the same as $\tau_X$ an underlying set?

Comment: I mean that, strictly speaking, the definition you've given of freeness takes an arbitrary functor $G$ as input, whereas in (3), (4), and (5) you've only defined categories. However, again, traditionally $G$ is the underlying set functor most of the time. In the case of $\text{Top}$ I mean the set $X$ on which the topology is defined, ignoring the topology. Similarly for the metric space example. I don't understand your last question.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I thought once you know how to write out the morphism $\psi,$ from the category $\textbf{A},$ then the functor $G$ get to be defined for morphism like in $\textbf{(1)}.$  But in $\textbf{(1)},$ the definition for functor don't specfic how to describe $HA, HB,$ given you know how to write out $Hf$.  Also, what is a set valued functor?

Comment: You cannot write down $Hf$ unless you already know what is $HA$ and $HB$, in the same way that you cannot write down a continuous function before you know what its domain and codomain are supposed to be. So perhaps you misunderstood something.

Comment: @Trebor my apologies for my late reply.  For the definition of free objects, I think the implicit assumption is that $H$ as a functor in $\textbf{(1)}$, or $G$ in the definition $\textbf{(2)}$ for free object above in my post, is that $G$ is suppose to be a forgetful functor.