# $(F,f)$ as a pair consider as an "initial object" in definition about "free object" for non algebraic categories.

Tags: category-theory, notation, definition, functors

The following are taken from "Categories" by T.S.Blyth and *Arrows, Structures and Functors the categorical imperative* by Arbib and Manes

$\color{Green}{Background:}$

[From: Arbib and Manes]

$\textbf{(1) Definition for “free over an object with respect to a functor":}$  Let $G:\textbf{A}\to \textbf{B}$ be any functor, and  $B$ an object of $\textbf{B}.$  We say the pair $(A,\eta),$ where $A$ is an object of $\textbf{A}$ and $\eta:B\to GA$ is a morphism of $\textbf{B},$ is $\textbf{free over}$ $B$ $\textbf{with respect to}$ $G$ just in case $\eta;B\to GA$ has the couniversal property that given any morphism $f:B\to GA'$ with $A'$ any object of $\textbf{A,}$ there exists a unique $\textbf{A-}$morphism $\psi:A\to A';$ such that

Diagram 1

[image: Diagram 1]

We refer to $\eta$ as the $\textbf{inclusion of generators;}$ and call the unique $\psi$ satisfying the above diagram the $\textbf{A-morphic extension of } f$ (with respect to $G$).

[From Blyth]

$\textbf{(2) Definition:}$ Let $S$ be a non-empty $\textbf{set}$ and let $\textbf{C}$ be a concrete category.  Consider the category $\textbf{K}$ whose objects are pairs $(X,\alpha)$ consisting of an object $X$ of $\textbf{C}$ and a mapping $\alpha:S\to X.$ Define $\text{Mor}_{\textbf{K}}((X,\alpha),(Y,\beta))$ to be the set of all morphisms $h:X\to Y$ in $\textbf{C}$ such that $h\circ \alpha=\beta:$

[image]

An initial object $(F,f)$ in $\textbf{K}$ (when such exists) is called a $\textit{free }\textbf{C}-\textit{object on the set S}$ .

$\color{Red}{Questions:}$

I asked here in this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4769219/how-to-describe-free-objects-ga-ga-for-non-algebraic-categories) about Definition (1) in regards to how to describe $GA$ for non algebraic category, like $\textbf{Top, Met}.$  It is for the purpose of determining what the free object in the category $\textbf{A}$ suppose to be.  I also consulted Blyth's text and found from Definition in (2), that the pair if the pair $(F,f)$ in $\textbf{K}$ is an initial object, then it is consider to be a "free $\textbf{C}$-object" on the set $S$.

What does it mean for the pair $(F,f)$ to be consider as an initial object?  Also, after determining that, will I be able to describe what $GA$ is suppose to be?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Re: your first question, ${\bf K}$ is a category and $(F,f)$ is an object in that category. So we just use the usual definition of "[initial object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_and_terminal_objects)" - $(F,f)$ is initial in ${\bf K}$ iff for every ${\bf K}$-object $(H,h)$ there is a unique ${\bf K}$-morphism $\mu: (F,f)\rightarrow (H,h)$.

Comment: @NoahSchweber for the unique $\textbf{K}$−
morphism $μ,$ don't one get the commutative diagram in Definition (2) above? In particular, $μ\circ f=h'$? Matching the morphisms in the commutative diagram from (2), don't $\mu=\alpha$?  So $\mu\circ f =h', \alpha\circ h= \beta$?  I am letting your $h$ to be relabled as $h'$.

Comment: @NoahSchweber is the notion of $(F,f)$ being an initial object from the notion of "comma" category?  Also, it is strange to consider something like a pair $(F,f)$ to be an object of a category.

Comment: "is the notion of $(F,f)$ being an initial object from the notion of "comma" category?" I don't understand what that means. There's a single notion of "initial object" - once you know what object you're looking at and what category you're looking at it in (here $(F,f)$ and ${\bf K}$ respectively) you just apply the definition. "It is strange to consider something like a pair $(F,f)$ to be an object of a category." I vehemently disagree: one of the big ideas in category theory is that we can build categories whose objects are, themselves, complicated category-involving things.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I meant slice category as a special case of comma category [here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_category) When you explain what an initial object with the map $\mu:(F,f)\to (H,h),$ how does it relate to the commutative diagram in Definition $\textbf{(2)}$ above.  Also, whether $(F,f)$ is either initial terminal, how does that affect how one chooses what $X,S$ are suppose to be in definition for $\textbf{(2)}$ above, in particular what $X$ is suppose to be as a free object in category $\textbf{K}?$